# Read data from barcode

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have one question regarding about retrieving Barcode data.

Below screen shot is the my java application.
[image]

For example, the barcode data have "12345-6789".
I put cursor on "Mo No." and scan barcode, System will read barcode and display on "Mo No." filled as "12345-6789"

But what I  want is "12345" in Mo No. and "6789" in Container No. Once I scanned barcode. 
How should I implement the code.
Please advice.Thanks.

Comment: What do you know to be constant? If the length of the first set of numbers is always 5 you can just use substrings.

Comment: Even you can split them with `-`.

Comment: @Arc676 the number can be different and will not always 5

Comment: Of course you need to come up with a criterium based on which you decide where the first string ends and where the second one starts. In your case the criterium is obviously that the first string ends immediately before the dash and the second starts immediately after the dash, so it should be a no brainer. But of course you need to know the basics of strings. Read the doc about String class to find the String methods to use to parse your string; f.ex. `substring` and `indexOf`, or `split` if you are OK with dealing with regular expressions.

Comment: So does your string always have a dash in the middle? Do you always want to separate the strings separated by this dash?

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

```
String toSplit = "12345-6789";
String a;
String b;
//check if string contains your split-char with [string#contains][2])
if(toSplit.contains("-")
{
  //split takes RegularExpression!
  String[] parts = toSplit.split("-");
  a = parts[0]; // =12345
  b = parts[1]; // =6789
}
else
{
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(toSplit + " does not contain -");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just ignore whatever after dash -

for example:

```
    String barcode="12345-6789";
    System.out.println(barcode.substring(0,barcode.indexOf("-"))); //this will only print whatever before first occurance of '-'
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 12345